# Is the description of the '--dereference-command-link-symlink-to-dir' option in the GNU Coreutils manual for the ls utility wrong?

Tags: command-line, directory, symbolic-link

Below is the text in question from the manuaul.

> **`--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir`**
>
> Do not dereference symbolic links, with one exception: if a command line argument specifies a symbolic link that refers to a directory, show information for that directory rather than for the link itself. This is the default behavior when no other dereferencing-related option has been specified (`--classify` (`-F`), `--directory` (`-d`), (`-l`), `--dereference` (`-L`), or `--dereference-command-line` (`-H`)).

Below are some commands I ran on my terminal.

```
$ touch myfile.txt
$ ln --symbolic myfile.txt symlink_myfile
$ ls --classify symlink_myfile 
symlink_myfile@
```

If the default behavior is to not dereference symbolic links unless a dereferencing-related option has been specified, then why does ls --classify produce 'symlink_myfile@'?

A dereferencing option, --classify, was specified so my symbolic link should have been dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

The `man` page for `ls` (and most other GNU programs) is only a very simplified summary. In your case, it says that `--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir` is the default unless a dereferencing-related option such as `-F` is given, but it does not say what happens about dereferencing when `-F` *is* given (so it is not wrong, merely incomplete). The entry about `-F` is not helpful either:

```
-F, --classify
        append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

More helpful information is available in the full documentation, which can be accessed with `info ls` or [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting):

```
‘-F’
‘--classify’
‘--indicator-style=classify’
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’.  The file
     type indicators are ‘/’ for directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links,
     ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets, ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.  Do not follow symbolic links listed on the command
     line unless the ‘--dereference-command-line’ (‘-H’),
     ‘--dereference’ (‘-L’), or
     ‘--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir’ options are specified.
```

So `-F` does not dereference by default.

Comment: Thanks very much. This helps.